# sequence increment with 2018AA00001 in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have created generate_letters & generate_num table using below query

```
select chr(i) as letter from generate_series(65,90) i;

select lpad(i::text,6,'0') as num from generate_series(1,100000) i;
```

after doing cross join with two tables using below query

```
select concat_ws('','2018',gl1.letter,gl2.letter,d.num) as seq
from       generate_letters gl1
cross join generate_letters gl2
cross join generate_num d limit 10;
```

i am getting the out put result (

```
2018AA000001
 2018AA000002
 2018AA000003
 2018AA000004
 2018AA000005
```

)

but how i need to use sequence for column(bill_id) increment using above query.
please suggest me.

Comment: Use a regular numeric primary key and write a function that converts the numbers to your desired format for output.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence and then use the `DEFAULT` clause for the required expression.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/56bcd/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE yourseq INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1; 

CREATE TABLE yourtable 
  ( 
     bill_id   TEXT DEFAULT '2018AA'||lpad(NEXTVAL('yourseq'::regclass)::text, 6 
     , '0' ), 
     bill_desc TEXT 
  ); 


INSERT INTO yourtable(bill_desc) VALUES ('Telephone Bill');
INSERT INTO yourtable(bill_desc) VALUES ('Water Bill');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * FROM yourtable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/56bcd/1/0)**:

```
|      bill_id |      bill_desc |
|--------------|----------------|
| 2018AA000001 | Telephone Bill |
| 2018AA000002 |     Water Bill |
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, can i extend bill_id 2018AB,2018AC,2018AD like (2018AB000001) after complete the first sequence using above query.